# Set $A \subset R$ has the property that if $x \in A$ then $2x^2-1 \in A$. Is the set A can have exactly 100 elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set $A \subset R$ has the property that if $x \in A$ then $2x^2-1 \in A$. Is the set A can have exactly  100 elements?

My try:
suppose that elements are $x,2x^2-1,4x^2-3,8x^2-9,...,2^{100}x^2-2^{100}-1$ ( $101$ elements ),

so $x=2^{100}x^2-2^{100}-1,x\neq -1$ , or $x=1+2^{-100}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n} = -\sqrt{(a_{n-1}+1)/2}$ for $n = 2 \ldots 100$.